# Why am i getting NULL EXCEPTION in the following code?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am getting `NULLREFERENCEEXCEPTION` for update query in a gridview.

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(Object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
   TextBox txtname = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtname1");
   cmd.Connection = con;
   cmd.CommandText = "update test1 set Name='" + txtname.Text + "' where Roll_No = '" 
                     + GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString() + "'";
   con.Open();
   int temp = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   if (temp == 1)
   {
      Label1.Text = "Record updated sucessfully"; 
   }
   GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
   FillGrid();
   con.Close();        
}
```

Comment: Please use a debugger to find out which thing is null exactly. There's lots of possibilities in your code, and we can't guess.

Comment: what sort of debugger?

Comment: put your gridview structure here.

Comment: MSDN article on debugging asp.net: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2faa92k(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are many but some of the possibilities are

```
TextBox txtname = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtname1");
```

There is no text box in the row. Due to some reason.

```
GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString()
```

The above value is null.

The other reasons could be you might be binding it on `page_load` rather than `page_load (!Page.IsPostBack)`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've the correct control name and check for null

```
if(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtname1")!=null)
{
  //your code
}
```

Debug through your code and see where it generates exception.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in order to debug it.

```
try{ 
TextBox txtname = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtname1");
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText = "update test1 set Name='" + txtname.Text + "' where Roll_No = '" + GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString() + "'";
con.Open();
int temp = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (temp == 1)
{ Label1.Text = "Record updated sucessfully"; }
else{Label1.Text = "Updating failure";}
GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
FillGrid();
con.Close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to verify the source of problem:

```
   TextBox txtname = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtname1") as TestBox;
   if(txtname is null)
   {
     Response.Write("Unable to find txtname");
     return;
   }
```

And if your grid is in a ContentPlaceHolder of a Master Page, then the Id of your control will change at runtime. You can set the "ClientIdMode" property of textbox to "static" so that the ID remains same at runtime.

Comment: i got an exception "unable to find txtname"

Comment: This is the message from the code. Set the "ClientIDMode" property of textbox "txtname1" to "Static" and try again.